# jquery fadeIn fadeOut effect

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a span element:

```
<span id="signInResult" style="border: 1px solid white;">html in here</span>
```

when the jquery ajax success fires I would like the span to immediately turn green and then fade back to the default white color:

```
success: function(msg){
  $("#signInResult").css('border-style', 'solid');
  $("#signInResult").css('border-color', 'green');
  $("#signInResult").fadeIn(300).css('border-color', 'white').fadeIn(300);
}
```

I have tried a number of variations of the fadeIn and fadeOut.. the current version above doesn't seem to do anything.... best way to do this to get desire result?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `animate`. It changes the css properties given slowly to the given values over the specified timeframe. FadeIn/FadeOut only deal with `opacity` and `display`.

Try:

```
success:function(msg) {
    $("#signInResult").css('border-color', '#0f0').animate({'border-color': '#fff'}, 300);
}
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: That is GOLD! thanks.  minor syntax point  the common should be a colon:  {'border-color': '#fff'}    thanks!

Comment: Note that (as explained on the doco page linked in this answer) `.animate()` doesn't work on colours unless you include [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) (or some other colour plugin).

Comment: ok thanks for that tip.  i have jqUI CDN.. Los F's code has been tested and it works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

As your question mentions that you want to change the color of the border, for animating colors try this:

<kbd>http://jsbin.com/anubin/1/edit</kbd>

```
 $(function() {
    $("#signInResult").css('border-style', 'solid');
    $("#signInResult").css('border-color', 'green');
    $("#signInResult").hide().fadeIn(300);

    $("#signInResult").animate({
        borderColor: "white",
        width: 500
      }, 1000 );
 });
```

`jquery ui` plugin required.